How to check data in past promql
Let's say I want to check a metric in past. For instance if today is monday and it's 12 o'clock, I want to check thursday between 17 - 19. Is this query correct?
rate(metric_part[5m] offset 4d5h) / rate(metric_whole[5m] offset 4d5h)

Also, how can I select a range time with this query? It returns an instant vector but I want to graph between 17 - 19. For example, is it correct to set offset to 4d7h to shift from 17 to 19 and set panel time selector to -2h?
If this is not correct how can I achieve it?
It is confusing since if in the prometheus panel I run this query it shows current date on data points on the graph. I checked in the google and seems it's default behaviour since you might join old and current data so date on the panel is always relative to now unless date selector is changed in the panel.
I also checked if there's any way to set from and to in promql for api request but seems it's not possible to set it in the promql.
edit 1: just realized my time offset is wrong and i'm using wrong offset. after editing it and checked graphs in grafana i think now i'm on a correct path.
screenshot from my graphs in grafana
left panel is using offset query and right panel is using time selector feature of grafana. but still could you verify if the whole thing im doing is correct?
